# Use StreamWriter or Stream outside of Function

Tags: c#, process, stream, iostream, streamwriter

I need to make a function to send commands to the Stream from process.StandardInput. I am having an error with the writer not be initialized. How can I fix this?

```
private StreamWriter writer;

private static void SendProcessCmd(string cmd)
{
    writer.WriteLine(cmd);
}

public static void CreateProcess()
{
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java.exe", args);
    processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

    try
    {
        using (Process process = Process.Start(processInfo))
        {
            writer = new StreamWriter(process.StandardInput.BaseStream);
            //writer = process.StandardInput;

            while (true)
            {
                String strInput = Console.ReadLine();
                writer.WriteLine(strInput);
            }

            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what problem are you having? I don't think your code will even compile.

Comment: `while(true)` with no way to break out of it. bold move :)

Comment: Ouch!! thats too rude to keep asking user to enter on console without breaking out of it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the specific error you are getting this is my best guess as to the problem.

You are creating an member variable `private StreamWriter writer` and then trying to access it inside `static` methods. Try making `StreamWriter writer` static.

Also, you have a `try` block, but no `catch` or `finally`. Either remove the `try` completely or add in some error handling with a `catch` block.

One last thing, I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish completely, but I would *strongly* suggest that you add a way to break out of your while loop. As it is, it is guaranteed to be an infinite loop.

Comment: Alright, I was under the impression if I made it static, I couldn't set the value for it from the function. There is a catch block and the while loop is just temporary for testing. I stripped the code down a lot so it would be easier to read.